# How to change icons on EMUI

Tags: nova-launcher, emui

I want to change a few particular icons without giving up the look of the EMUI.

I tried IconChanger, but it leaves a water mark on the new icon. I also tried NovaLauncher; however, it doesn't support font customization and I'm not a fan of the elongated font it uses.

Is there a way to change the icon files manually? Is there a launcher that will enable icon changes without changing other aspects of the GUI? Just to be clear I'm not looking for an icon pack. I want to make use of a few specific icons that I've created.

Answer (score 0):

a lancher won't change things like the notification panel and other UI elements you can get icon packs for android however i am not sure if EMUI default launcher supports them 
try and go to settings  search for font i know lawncher launcher support's icon packs and can change the font colour on the home screen

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.deletescape.lawnchair.plah&hl=en_US&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Dlawnchair&pcampaignid=APPU_1_WqyLXJP9KdqG1fAP2cKgyAE

what version of Android are you running?

Comment: try following this guide https://www.androidcentral.com/how-make-custom-icon-android?amp

Comment: what version of Android and EMUI are you using?